# How to prevent extrapolation using na.spline()

Tags: r, interpolation, cubic-spline

I'm having trouble with the `na.spline()` function in the `zoo` package. Although the documentation explicitly states that this is an *interpolation* function, the behaviour I'm getting includes extrapolation.

The following code reproduces the problem:

```
require(zoo)
vector <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,5,NA,7,8,NA,NA)
na.spline(vector)
```

The output of this *should* be:

```
NA NA NA NA NA NA  5  6  7  8  NA NA
```

This would be *interpolation* of the internal NA, leaving the trailing NAs in place. But, instead I get:

```
-1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

[According to the documentation](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/zoo/docs/na.approx), this shouldn't happen. Is there some way to avoid extrapolation?

I recognise that in my example, I could use *linear* interpolation, but this is a MWE. Although I'm not necessarily wed to the na.spline() function, I need some way to interpolate using cubic splines.

Comment: The issue appears to be with `stats::spline`: `spline(seq_along(vector), vector, xout=seq_along(vector))`. It's inconsistent with `approx`, which strictly does interpolation.

Comment: Achim has corrected the documentation in the development version of zoo.  Since the problem is not in zoo itself and zoo tries to be consistent with the core of R there is no actual change to the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior appears to be coming from the `stats::spline` function, e.g.,

```
spline(seq_along(vector), vector, xout=seq_along(vector))$y
# [1] -1  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Here is a work around, using the fact that `na.approx` strictly interpolates.

```
replace(na.spline(vector), is.na(na.approx(vector, na.rm=FALSE)), NA)
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA  5  6  7  8 NA NA
```

**Edit**

As @G.Grothendieck suggests in the comments below, another, no doubt more performant, way is:

```
na.spline(vector) + 0*na.approx(vector, na.rm = FALSE)
```

Comment: or `na.spline(vector) + 0*na.approx(vector, na.rm = FALSE)`

Comment: Brilliant shortcut @G.Grothendieck !